# How to only allow function to be called from the REPL, not by other functions?

Tags: python

*Context:*

I'm writing a personal python module to simplify some scripts I have lying around. One of the functions I have is untested and may have undesirable edge cases that I still have to consider. In order to not allow myself from relying on it from other modules or functions, I was wondering whether I could enforce it to raise an error if not called directly from the REPL.

I'm not asking whether this is a good idea or not. It obviously isn't because it defeats the purpose of writing a function in the first place. I'm wondering if is is possible in Python, and how to do it.

*Question:*

Is it possible to have a function raise an error if not called interactively? For example:

```py
def is_called_from_top_level():
    "How to implement this?"
    pass

def shady_func():
    "Only for testing at the REPL. Calling from elsewhere will raise."
    if not is_called_from_top_level():
        raise NotImplementedError("Shady function can only be called directly.")
    return True

def other_func():
    "Has an indirect call to shady."
    return shady_func()
```

And then at a REPL:

```py
[In:1] shady_func()
[Out:1] True
[In:2] other_func()
[Out:2] NotImplementedError: "Shady function can only be called directly."
```

Comment: The `inspect` module is probably your best bet for this.  `len(inspect.stack()) < 3` looks like it would be true only for code in a top-level called function, not anything nested deeper.

Comment: What is the exact REPL that you are you using ([standard python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html), [iPython](https://ipython.readthedocs.io), something else)?

Comment: ipython and jupyter console (I suppose they are the same?)

Comment: @dangom I have updated my answer to work with (my current versions of) Python / IPython / Jupyter. Still a bit of a hack, but works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER**: This is a bit of a hack, and may not work across different Python / IPython / Jupyter versions, but the underlying idea still holds, i.e. use `inspect` to get an idea of who is calling.

The code below was tested with Python 3.7.3, IPython 7.6.1 and Jupyter Notebook Server 5.7.8.

---

Using [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/inspect.html) (obviously), one can look for distinctive features of the *REPL* frame:

1. inside a **Jupyter Notebook** you can check if the `repr()` of the previous frame contain the string `'code <module>'`;
2. using **Python** / **IPython** you can check for the code representation of the previous frame to start at `line 1`.

In code, this would look like:

```py
import inspect


def is_called_from_top_level():
    "How to implement this?"
    pass


def shady_func():
    "Only for testing at the REPL. Calling from elsewhere will raise."
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    is_interactive = (
        'code <module>' in repr(frame.f_back)  # Jupyter
        or 'line 1>' in repr(frame.f_back.f_code))  # Python / IPython
    if not is_interactive:
        raise NotImplementedError("Shady function can only be called directly.")
    return True


def other_func():
    "Has an indirect call to shady."
    return shady_func()


shady_func()
# True
other_func()
# raises NotImplementedError
```

(*EDITED* to include support for both Jupyter Notebook and Python / IPython).

---

As suggested by @bananafish, this is actually a good use case for a decorator:

```
import inspect
import functools


def repl_only(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        frame = inspect.currentframe()
        is_interactive = (
            'code <module>' in repr(frame.f_back)  # Jupyter
            or 'line 1>' in repr(frame.f_back.f_code))  # Python / IPython
        if not is_interactive:
            raise NotImplementedError('Can only be called from REPL')
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped


@repl_only
def foo():
    return True


def bar():
    return foo()


print(foo())
# True
print(bar())
# raises NotImplementedError
```

Comment: Ah you're too fast!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Indeed an awesome hack!

Answer (score 4):

Try checking for `ps1` on `sys`.

```py
import sys

def dangerous_util_func(a, b):
    is_interactive = bool(getattr(sys, 'ps1', False))
    print(is_interactive)  # Prints True or False
    return a + b
```

You can even get fancy and make a decorator for this to make it more reusable.

```py
import sys
from functools import wraps


def repl_only(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        is_interactive = bool(getattr(sys, 'ps1', False))
        if not is_interactive:
            raise NotImplementedError("Can only be called from REPL")
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped


@repl_only
def dangerous_util_func(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Comment: This is indeed the perfect use case for a decorator.

Comment: This still allows `dangerous_util_func` to be called from other functions

Comment: Nice use of the decorator, but the method does not seem to work for IPython

Comment: @dangom for me it still raises the exception if it's a nested call. But it seems it might not work with ipython, are you using that?

Comment: yes, I suppose it doesn't work with ipython. Curious why sys.ps1 would change on a nested call in python and not ipython

Comment: It seems I misunderstood the requirement, I thought you wanted it to fail when called from a script, but always work in the repl, even if nested. You probably will have to use the `inspect` module to get this working exactly as intended, ipython or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that:

```
import inspect

def other():
    shady()

def shady():
    curfrm = inspect.currentframe()
    calframe = inspect.getouterframes(curfrm, 2)
    caller = calframe[1][3]

    if not '<module>' in caller::
        raise Exception("Not an acceptable caller")

    print("that's fine")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    shady()
    other()
```

The module [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) allows you to get information such as the function's caller. You may have to dig a bit deeper if you have edge cases....

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the comment to the OP suggesting looking at the stack trace, @norok2 's solution based on direct caller inspection, and by @bananafish 's use of the decorator, I came up with an alternative solution that does not require `inspect` nor `sys`.
The idea is to throw and catch to get a handle on a traceback object (essentially our stack trace), and then do the direct caller inspection.

```py
from functools import wraps


def repl_only(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            raise Exception
        except Exception as e:
            if "module" not in str(e.__traceback__.tb_frame.f_back)[-10:]:
                raise  NotImplementedError(f"{func.__name__} has to be called from the REPL!")
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped


@repl_only
def dangerous_util_func(a, b):
    return a + b

def foo():
    return dangerous_util_func(1, 2)
```

Here `dangerous_util_func` will run and `foo` will throw.